# How to draw line between two ellipses?

Tags: wpf

Well it's pretty difficult to summarize my problem. Let just say I create two ellipses dynamically. And now I want to draw a line between them. I can't use the margins of ellipses to position the Y axis of my line because I am using grid rows to position my ellipses vertically. Can someone help?

```
Path path = new Path();
path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
path.StrokeThickness = 2;
Binding binding = new Binding("center") { ElementName = "ellipse" };
Binding binding_to = new Binding("center") { ElementName = "ellipse1" };
LineGeometry lineGeometry = new LineGeometry();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lineGeometry, LineGeometry.StartPointProperty, binding);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lineGeometry, LineGeometry.EndPointProperty, binding_to);
path.Data = lineGeometry;
map_grid.Children.Add(path);
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with sample code. Like, are the eclipses in different rows or columns, what's the size of eclipse or the grid row/column.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: `ellipse` and `ellipse1` are EllipseGeometries that are declared in XAML? Otherwise setting ElementName would be pointless. If so, `center` is not a property of EllipseGeometry. It is `Center` instead. Also note that you do not actually need a Binding when the ellipses don't move. We can not help you if you don't give us a minimum of information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nope. ellipse and ellipse1 are not EllipseGeometries. Like I said, ellipses are created dynamically depending on what value the user enters. And no, the user does not specify x and y points. x is calculated and y is added to a grid row depending on some other value that the user enters. And please tell me what other information you require.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't use a Grid. Better use two Path elements with appropriate EllipseGeometries and use the Center points of the EllipseGeometries as endpoints of a LineGeometry in a third Path element. Put them all in a common Canvas:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="{Binding ElementName=e1, Path=Center}"
                          EndPoint="{Binding ElementName=e2, Path=Center}"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Path Fill="Red">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="e1" Center="100,100" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Path Fill="Green">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="e2" Center="200,300" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thank You for replying. Like I said before, my problem is very difficult to summarize. Also, everything is created dynamically. I have to use grid. Isn't there any way I can draw a line between two dynamically created ellipses?

Comment: You can of course also create these elements and the Bindings in code (if that is what you mean with "dynamically").

Comment: I tried to code for it. But it's not working. Can you please help me with where I am doing wrong? I am updating my question with the code.